# Keycloak redirect_uri from docker container with Spring Security (Jhispter)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-security, keycloak, jhipster

Hello I have some problems with keycloak and springBoot (jhipster) inside docker.

I hope I will be able to make myself understood

I want to locally launch all my components which are each in a container.

i have an angular front running behind an nginx

```
image: ngnix-with-my-angular-project:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
```

In my ngnix conf I have proxy pass like this

```
location /oauth2 {
   proxy_pass http://myprojectapp:8080/oauth2;
}

location /login {
   proxy_pass http://myprojectapp:8080/login;
}
```

In my keycloak docker conf I added in this env variables:

```
PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
```

In my application, named myprojectapp springBoot (jhispter) I have the following conf

```
myprojectapp:
.
.
.
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_OIDC_ISSUER_URI=http://keycloak:9080/auth/realms/myproject
```

My Angular project is available at the following address: http://localhost:8000/

I'm trying to connect via keycloak

http://keycloak:9080/auth/realms/myproject/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=web_app&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=YYY&**redirect_uri=http://myprojectapp:8080**/login/oauth2/code/oidc&nonce=XXX

I enter my credentials then I am redirected to the internal url of my myprojectapp's docker

http://**myprojectapp:8080**/login/oauth2/code/oidc?state=WWW&session_state=YYY&code=ZZZ

I don't know how to configure the redirect_uri to be redirected to my angular frontend

**redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/login/oauth2/code/oidc**

Comment: Nginx needs to forward `X-Forwarded*` headers to the app, so app will be aware of reverse proxy. Of course app must be able to process that headers. E.g. https://tomgregory.com/spring-boot-behind-load-balancer-using-x-forwarded-headers/

Answer (score 1):

Thank @JanGaraj
i've added this in my nginx conf

```
server {
listen 80;
.
.
.
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

And i expose my front to 80 instead of 8000 in docker

```
image: ngnix-with-my-angular-project:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

The following conf doesn't not redirect me to 8000

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_protocol_port;
```

Good enough for me, thanks